# The equivalent statement of torsion-free quasi-coherent sheaves of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

The problem comes from Volumn I, (7.4.3), Grothendieck's EGA. For a scheme $X$, denote the sheaf of rational functions by $\mathscr{R}(X)$.

**Corollary (7.4.3)**. Over an integral scheme $X$, any torsion-free, quasi-coherent and rank-$1$  $O_X$-module sheaf (denote this sheaf by $\mathscr{F}$) is isomorphic to a subsheaf of $\mathscr{R}(X)$. The converse also holds.

First, I think the statement should restric to nonzero sheaves.
I know how to prove the direction "$\Rightarrow$".

On the other hand, assume $\mathscr{F}$ is  a nonzero subsheaf of $\mathscr{R}(X)$, then I can show that it is torsion-free. If $\mathscr{F}$ is quasi-coherent, then I can also show that $\mathscr{F}$ is of rank-$1$. The key problem: how to prove $\mathscr{F}$ is quasi-coherent?

I know that subsheaves of constant sheaves may be non-constant. I think the corollary should be modified to the following.

**New Statement**. Over an integral scheme $X$, any torsion-free, quasi-coherent and rank-$1$  $O_X$-module sheaf (denote this sheaf by $\mathscr{F}$) is isomorphic to a nonzero and quasi-coherent subsheaf of $\mathscr{R}(X)$. The converse also holds.

Comment: Yes, $\mathscr{R}(X)$ has non quasi-coherent subsheaves.

Comment: @Roland, can you give a reference or an example?

Comment: If $U$ is an open subset and $j:U\to X$ the open inclusion, then the extension by zero $j_!\mathscr{R}(X)|_U$ is a sub-$\mathscr{O}_X$-module which is not quasicoherent in general.

Comment: @Roland, I agree with you. I believe my new statement is correct and EGA I 7.4.3 is defective.

Comment: Yeah probably, but if you have a statement like "If we have $A, B, C, D$ then we have $E$", for me the converse statement is not really clear. It may very well be "if we have $A, B, C$ and $E$ then we have $D$, which in this case would be "if $X$ is an integral scheme, $\mathscr{F}$ is torsion-free, quasicoherent and isomorphic to a subsheaf of $\mathscr{R}(X)$ then $\mathscr{F}$ is a rank 1 $\mathscr{O}_X$-module. (And indeed non-zero should have been assumed).